# How to remove a key-value pair from a dictionary after accessing it?

Tags: python

I'm making a text based game for a class where the player moves through rooms and collects items while trying to avoid the room with the villain in it. I've gotten the game to work correctly, however I need to make it so that when the player grabs the item from the room, they can't keep picking it up over and over again. I know I need to delete the key-value pair from the dictionary after I access it, but I can't figure out how to access the key-value and then delete it. I've tried using the **del** function to delete it after it iterates, but that causes an error.

```
def show_instructions():
    print('Welcome to Rocket Escape!\n')
    print('Collect the 6 spaceship parts to escape the planet before the evil Corporate Mining Company catches you!')
    print('Movement Commands: North, South, East, West')
    print('To pickup an item and add it to inventory, type "Acquire"')
    print('To exit the game, type: Exit')


rooms = {
    'House': {'North': 'Fields', 'East': 'Library'},
    'Library': {'West': 'House', 'item': 'Map'},
    'Fields': {'North': 'Fuel Depot', 'East': 'Lab', 'South': 'House', 'West': 'Launch Pad', 'item': 'Rations'},
    'Launch Pad': {'East': 'Fields', 'item': 'Keys'},
    'Fuel Depot': {'South': 'Fields', 'East': 'Front Gate', 'item': 'Fuel'},
    'Lab': {'North': 'Shed', 'West': 'Fields', 'item': 'Spacesuit'},
    'Shed': {'South': 'Lab', 'item': 'Ammunition'},
    'Front Gate': {'West': 'Fuel Depot', 'item': 'Corporate Mining Company!'}}


def player_stat():
    print('')
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room))
    print('Current Inventory: {}'.format(current_inv))
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        print('\nYou see {}!'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
    print('')


current_inv = []
current_room = 'House'
player_move = ''

show_instructions()

while True:
    player_stat()
    player_move = input('Enter your move:\n').title()
    if player_move == 'Exit':
        print('Exiting. Thanks for playing!')
        break
    elif player_move in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][player_move]
    elif player_move == 'Acquire':
        current_inv.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
        print('You acquired {}!'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
    if current_room == 'Front Gate':
        print('Oh no! You\'ve been captured by the Corporate Mining Company!')
        break
    else:
        print('\nInvalid Move')
```

#I tried to use the del function but that deleted the whole key-value before iterating

Comment: Do you want to remove when `player_move == 'Acquire'` ?

Comment: Oh that could work. I assume you mean write it so that when the player uses 'Acquire' to pick up the item the program concurrently deletes it from the dictionary correct? As long as the user can't cause a KeyError by trying to acquire the deleted key then that would work for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `if` condition:

```
elif player_move == 'Acquire':
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        current_inv.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
        print('You acquired {}!'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
        del rooms[current_room]['item']
    else:
        print('No items in the current room')
```

And the other a bit more concise solution is to use `.pop()` method:

```
elif player_move == 'Acquire':
    if current_item := rooms[current_room].pop('item', None):
        current_inv.append(current_item)
        print(f'You acquired {current_item}')
    else:
        print('No items in the current room')
```

`:=` is called the walrus operator if you aren't familiar with it.